# difference between org.apache.hbase -hbase and -hbase-client

Tags: java, maven, hbase

I'm working with project that uses HBase and need to use some API for both working with data (Put and other classes) and schema(HTable, HColumn etc). I found two maven dependencies to work with it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

They both have similar classes, so what library should I use and what is difference between them?